# PhpStorm - How to format HTML code in PHP tags

Tags: php, html, formatting, phpstorm, auto-indent

I don't understand how can I format correctly HTML code when is surrounded between PHP tags when I click "Auto-Indent Lines".

What do I expect:

[image]

What PhpStorm does when I click "Auto-Indent Lines".:

[image]

Comment: Can you not just hit the tab button instead of clicking the auto-indent?

Comment: The problem is that I have .php files with hundreds/thousand lines of code that I want to re-format

Comment: PhpStorm is formatting the php, not the html that the php will generate. So there is not much you can do about that unless you use html templates in separate files that PhpStorm will recognize as html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see comments in [WI-17786](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-17786). In general, it's not currently possible to format HTML mixed with PHP

Comment: I had already seen this page, but I thought concern another bug (after all my english sucks, so ...). Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can change that behaviour in the PHPStorm Preferences. 
Open your Preferences... 
When the Window opens; type **Code Style** to search for that Keyword.
Then under the Menu select HTML.... Here You can decide how your HTML would be formatted or you may select any Language like PHP...

However; you may have to restart PHPStorm for the Effect to take place.